# How can I add timeout functionality to withWatermark in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

in my Spark Structured Streaming code I am receiving user operations from Kafka and need to store the counts of operations per_user_and_15_min_window in Parquet (append mode).

Events timestamp don't match reality, they can belong to the past and may come out-of-order up to a point.

Data flow is like this: I may receive data for february 2017 and after that maybe data for november 2016, BUT once I have received data for a userID and period (15min) I would like watermark functionality to close the aggregation (and append it to Parquet) if no more data for that pair userID_period is received within X minutes timeout (or via some other kind of trigger).

Code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

//Create Spark Session
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local[2]")

val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", ipaddress_port)
  .option("subscribe", "calls-topic")
  .load()
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).as("user_record")).select("user_record.*")
  .appName("LearningStructuredStreaming")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Here's the aggregation query

```
//Write aggregation query
val aggregationQuery = df.withColumn("MyDateTime", from_unixtime((col("attributes.START_TIME")/1000), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").cast(TimestampType))
.withWatermark("MyDateTime", "15 minutes")
.groupBy(window(col("MyDateTime"), "15 minutes"), col("attributes.USER_ID"))
.agg(count("attributes.OPERATION_ID").as("#Operations"))
.writeStream
.format("parquet")
.option("path", "C:/output_parquet")
.option("checkpointLocation", "C:/checkpoint")
.outputMode("append")
.start()
```

Output of the above code looks like this (reading from Parquet output folder):

```
+------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
|window                                    |USER_ID     |#Operations |
+------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
|[2017-07-27 17:00:00.0,2017-07-27 17:15.. |User1       |321         |
|[2017-07-27 17:00:00.0,2017-07-27 17:15.. |User2       |571         |
|[2017-07-27 17:00:00.0,2017-07-27 17:15.. |User3       |272         |
|[2017-07-27 17:15:00.0,2017-07-27 17:30.. |User1       |351         |
|[2017-07-27 17:15:00.0,2017-07-27 17:30.. |User2       |491         |
|[2017-07-27 17:15:00.0,2017-07-27 17:30.. |User3       |277         |
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some progress, but still not there.

Here I add a new column referrencing current time and this is the column I will use for watermark.

```
//Write aggregation query
val aggregationQuery = df.withColumn("MyDateTime", from_unixtime((col("attributes.START_TIME")/1000), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").cast(TimestampType))
.withColumn("timestamp", current_timestamp())
.withColumn("data_window", window(col("MyDateTime"), "15 minutes"))
.withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minutes")
.groupBy(window(col("timestamp").as("processing_window"), "1 minutes"), col("old_window"), col("attributes.USER_ID"))
.agg(count("attributes.OPERATION_ID").as("#Operations"))
.writeStream
.format("parquet")
.option("path", "C:/output_parquet")
.option("checkpointLocation", "C:/checkpoint")
.outputMode("append")
.start()
```

The output would look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------+------+
|processing_window                            |data_window                                  |USER_ID           |#Operations|
+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------+------+
|[2018-03-22 13:11:00.0,2018-03-22 13:12:00.0]|[2015-08-17 21:00:00.0,2015-08-17 21:15:00.0]|User12234         |2     |
|[2018-03-22 13:20:00.0,2018-03-22 13:21:00.0]|[2015-08-17 21:00:00.0,2015-08-17 21:15:00.0]|User12234         |2     |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12241         |5808  |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12237         |900   |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12243         |953   |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12247         |2402  |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12238         |939   |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12239         |1311  |
|[2018-03-22 13:11:00.0,2018-03-22 13:12:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12239         |1     |
|[2018-03-22 13:11:00.0,2018-03-22 13:12:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12240         |2373  |
|[2018-03-22 13:20:00.0,2018-03-22 13:21:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12240         |2373  |
|[2018-03-22 13:20:00.0,2018-03-22 13:21:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12244         |4121  |
|[2018-03-22 13:11:00.0,2018-03-22 13:12:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12244         |4121  |
|[2018-03-22 13:11:00.0,2018-03-22 13:12:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12234         |1430  |
|[2018-03-22 13:20:00.0,2018-03-22 13:21:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:00:00.0,2015-08-18 20:15:00.0]|User12234         |1430  |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:15:00.0,2015-08-18 20:30:00.0]|User12241         |5574  |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:15:00.0,2015-08-18 20:30:00.0]|User12237         |907   |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:15:00.0,2015-08-18 20:30:00.0]|User12243         |1059  |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:15:00.0,2015-08-18 20:30:00.0]|User12247         |2348  |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:15:00.0,2015-08-18 20:30:00.0]|User12238         |828   |
|[2018-03-22 13:02:00.0,2018-03-22 13:03:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:15:00.0,2015-08-18 20:30:00.0]|User12239         |1302  |
|[2018-03-22 13:11:00.0,2018-03-22 13:12:00.0]|[2015-08-18 20:15:00.0,2015-08-18 20:30:00.0]|User12240         |2433  |
```

This solution allows me to process data from the past and append it to Parquet, no matter in which order the data arrives.

But I'm still struggling with forcing the data to be appended to Parquet right after it has been processed by Spark. Because of the watermark, the state is kept and data will not be output until further batches are processed, which is a pitty because this is introducing unnecessary delay.

Do you have a better approach?